# Sport Stack Exchange vs Wikipedia

Tags: discussion, answers, wikipedia

I have observed that a lot of questions from sport sector find easy reply on the [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org).

Normally Wikipedia will be well updated, so is better for internet users to search info on that site rather then here. So info on Sport Stack Exchange can be wrong especially when they talk about records and trivia, is that a problem?

In that case how can we solve it?

Comment: I have removed the [bug] tag from this post. It seems a valid [discussion] question. Personally I dont see any reason to downvote this post.

Comment: related: [Is a question that specifically asks for a summary of a broad topic valuable to Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234642/165773) _"Stack Exchange Q&A model has been optimized to only cover topics where Wikipedia falls short (["long tail"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)). It is **intended to complement, not to compete** against Wikipedia..."_

Answer (score 8):

If the answer to the question is *truly* easy to find, then **the question should *probably* be downvoted** because it "does not show any research effort" as well as that it quite possibly is "not useful" in increasing the corpus of knowledge on the Internet.

However, beware of the fact that just because a question is trivial to answer to you (or someone else in particular), that doesn't necessarily make it easy to answer **for someone not intimitely familiar with the subject matter.** Sometimes not knowing what to look for might not be able to answer the question as easily. If the question approaches the subject matter from an angle which does not lend itself well to researching through established methods, absolutely consider posting an answer as well, or at the very least a link or two to resources. That could even be something as simple as links to specific page sections on Wikipedia or similar, posted as a comment.

In general, questions often don't get voted on enough. Let's have more question voting in general, and absolutely don't forget to upvote good questions (quite possibly including questions where the OP shows that they have tried and failed to find the answer!).

Answer (score 4):

Post correct answers. Really, that is all there is.

If there is an answer that is wrong according to you, you can downvote it and/or comment why you think it is wrong. Also, you can post your own answer containing the 'correct' information.

SE is not trying to be Wikipedia, and they are not exchangeable in any way. You could link to the relevant article on Wikipedia in your post. Make your post self-containing though.

Comment: The question was written about sport questions. I think that there are a lot of good questions in sport section where the reply is easy to find in wikipedia...

Comment: If the answer is so easy to find on Wikipedia, the one posting the question shouldn't ask it in the first place.

Comment: I agreed but it is not difficult to find questions like those, maybe only to take badges or reputations score (I think also some of my questions were not necessary, maybe taking a look on wikipedia...)