# In my opinion the system is to open to abuse by high ranking members

Tags: feature-request, rant

I have seen the ugly side of the community run system as of late and I implore anyone whom has the ability to do so to consider restricting control by high ranking members; at least in some way mitigate the mob like mentality that can come from a few high ranking members banding together and playing the wild west with posts.

I am not going to point anyone out its not my intention however it pains me to see a system that can allow childish actions.

I will give an example, I had my post put on hold as it was "too broad", this seems ridiculous to me and I will tell you why, that kind of statement is completely subject to someone opinion its not absolute 3+1 is absolute the only answer can be 4. When "moderators" and high ranking member's can use a term like too broad. It just facilitates the regular member's banding together and throwing holds everywhere according to their definition of too broad.

I heard the counter argument that it's community based and the community decides this however is just about never the case, there is the few that hang around together in the chats on the boards, that run around placing post on hold together, group down voting, spamming there counter argument in the comments. Then hundreds of other members whom have not reached a high rank or just don't have the time or care.

The simple fact is my post was put on hold by the same 8-10 members rejects for re-opening by the same 8-10 member's and inevitably after the didn't like my request down voted by the same 8-10 members.

There is a very ugly side to the system we use, people even if they feel they are doing the correct thing will abuse the system sometimes. I feel this can be minimized by taking certain powers away from moderators and higher ranking members.

At the end of the day I can walk away and use some other forums or the like its not a huge deal in the grand scheme of things. However thousands of user will suffer due to these little what I like to call mobs of users.

I kinda expect to get down voted but its my 2 cents and I can at least say I tried :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is pure rant.

Comment: Its not a rant its a reflection of the current system(at least in my eyes), little rude to call it a rant.

Comment: I don't see any suggestions you're making here. You just criticize the system and this whole wall of text can be written in three words "the system sucks". So, isn't it a rant?

Comment: Of course not I am pointing out why the system is not efficient, it concerns me about the level of hostility you approach with.

Comment: What is your question? TL;DR please

Comment: @Jan think I found it, buried deep within the text: "take certain powers away from moderators and higher ranking members".

Comment: Mitigate it a little better atleast

Comment: Do you have anything constructive here? All I see is complaints without any regard to how we got here, nor with any concrete suggestions for improvements.

Comment: @ShadowWizard as in, even less closing? No, thanks. He can go to Yahoo Answers.

Comment: I feel whatever I say will be rejected here, as minds seem to be made well before reading the post

Comment: @Jan yup, sounds like heaven for those who don't care about quality.

Comment: I may be seeing a legitimate feature request here: users who closed a question shouldn't be shown the respective reopen queue item. And even then I disagree.

Comment: `as minds seem to be made well before reading the post`, same minds have made/contributed to this community over the course of years.

Comment: How about you present us with the post, ask why it is too broad, and what you could potentially do to avoid having it closed us such? Then we can either tell you what to do, or we could even come to the conclusion that it really shouldn't have been closed. Wouldn't that be far more productive?

Comment: @bennyboy you're accusing Shadow of hostility for the word rant when you go with "ugly", "mob like", "wild west", "childish", "ridiculous", "throwing holds everywhere", "hang around", "run around", "spamming" and then again "ugly" and "mobs". Dude, you have a beam in your eye.

Comment: Be happy, wear hats! :)

Comment: I see even if its less rant like its still shunned upon by the powers that be http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243317/proposal-against-power-abuse-on-stack-sites-and-a-more-democratic-voting-system/243322#243322 it only takes a select few to ruin the system for everyone

Comment: It's a feature request @IgotaHat. If you look in the help center you'll see a mention that downvotes on it can be as much as a "nay" vote. It seems you would benefit from getting to know the system a bit better and seeing why certain things are in place before you judge it the way you do.

Comment: Please read the [help] to know how downvotes are different for feature-requests.

Answer (score 22):

There is no way that you know this to be true:

> The simple fact is my post was put on hold by the same 8-10 members rejects for re-opening by the same 8-10 member's and inevitably after the didn't like my request down voted by the same 8-10 members.

Down votes are anonymous.

I looked through your profile on other sites and see two questions closed as Unclear What You're Asking, none as Too Broad. If you provide a link, we could check whether the first half of your sentence (that the same people both closed it and voted Keep Closed in the re-open queue) was true or not. I can't even tell if your question was closed by 5 users or a single moderator.

It is clear that you see no value in the "too broad" closing reason. That is unfortunate because it's one of the reasons these sites work. Let me tell you how to deal with it. You simply break your questions into several different questions, and do some of the research yourself. Take a "too broad" question like "How do I get a better job?" - hidden in there are questions about finding jobs to apply to, writing a good resume and cover letter, doing well on a phone screen, doing well in an interview, negotiating a compensation package, and giving notice at your current job. (Even those may be too broad, I'm giving an analogy here.) The more crisp the questions are, the better a fit they are for our sites. "Does it get really cold in Venice?" is not as good as "Do most people wear a sweater in Venice in November and December?" - it doesn't need a definition of "really cold", for one thing.

If you link to your question (and perhaps ease up a little on telling us how terrible the people are who closed it) we may be able to suggest edits that will either make it re-openable or help you understand how to break it up into answerable questions.

Comment: related: [Is a question that specifically asks for a summary of a broad topic valuable to Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234642/165773)